# Error: The method 'fromBytes' isn't defined for the type 'VCard' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, parsing-error, flutter-qrcode

I'm encountering an error in my Flutter code where I'm trying to parse a vCard using the vcard package. However, I'm getting the error message "The method 'fromBytes' isn't defined for the type 'VCard'". Here's the relevant code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';
import 'package:vcard/vcard.dart';

class QRScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QRScanPageState createState() => _QRScanPageState();
}

class _QRScanPageState extends State<QRScanPage> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: QRView(
              key: qrKey,
              onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Name',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        parseVCard(result!.code);
      });
    });
  }

  void parseVCard(String vCardString) {
    final vCard = VCard.fromBytes(utf8.encode(vCardString));
    nameController.text = vCard.formattedName.value ?? '';
    emailController.text = vCard.email.value ?? '';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: QRScanPage(),
  ));
}
```

I have already added the vcard package to my pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: datacollector
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  http: ^0.13.4



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.4.0
  vcard: any
  vcard_parser: ^0.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

How can I resolve this error and successfully parse the vCard data from a byte array? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to change the function fromBytes to another function called  fromFormattedString this is my code after changing

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';
import 'package:vcard/vcard.dart';

class QRScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QRScanPageState createState() => _QRScanPageState();
}

class _QRScanPageState extends State<QRScanPage> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: QRView(
              key: qrKey,
              onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Name',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        parseVCard(result!.code);
      });
    });
  }

  void parseVCard(String vCardString) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(vCardString);
    final vCardData = utf8.decode(bytes);
    final vCard = VCard.fromFormattedString(vCardData);
    nameController.text = vCard.formattedName.value ?? '';
    emailController.text = vCard.email.value ?? '';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: QRScanPage(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of fromBytes or fromFormattedString in the vcard package, what makes you think those methods exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pubspec.yaml file indicates you are using [simple_vcard_parser package](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_vcard_parser), the example shows you should be able to create a VCard instance by calling `VCard(string)`.

You should be able to change your parseVCard method to simply be:

```
void parseVCard(String vCardString) {
    final vCard = VCard(vCardString);
}
```

You may need to add the import statement
`import 'package:simple_vcard_parser/simple_vcard_parser.dart';`
and remove the existing import of
`import 'package:vcard/vcard.dart';`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, now I have solved a problem I've been struggling with for a while